# Replacing character in magento product descriptions after import

Tags: magento, encoding, character

I just imported over 20k items into magento.

The original data was from an access DB.

In the descriptions, all the `"` are showing as `�`

for example, the original description reads:

This arrangement is approx. `32" - 34"` tall.

on the magento front-end it now reads:

This arrangement is approx. `32�-34�` tall.

Reimporting the data is not an option.... I need to be able to either have this shown correctly in magento front-end using a `hack`  or somehow replace all these characters with the proper characters in MySQL database, or somehow change the encoding...

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Anyone? I really need a solution to this.... if anyone has any suggestions please let me know

Answer (score 2):

Hi You need  to save csv in utf-8 format before import

Comment: yes, that would have been the preventative measure, but now i need to fix it... re-importing it is not an option at this point as i mentioned...

Comment: can you provide your site link

Answer (score 0):

I ended up exporting all the descriptions, did a find/replace in notepad, saved it as utf-8. and re-imported them back in  after other methods failed.

This wasn't what i wanted to go through again but i had no choice.